# How to make Facebook likes private?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-privacy

I know there's a way to hide what I like from my newsfeed and hide my activity log, but to illustrate my question...

Say I am friends with Joe and Nancy but they're not mutual friends. If I like Joe’s picture or post, and it doesn't show on my newsfeed, is there a way to hide my like from Nancy all together even if she were to go to his page and be able to see who all liked the picture (except for my like)? Hope that makes sense!

Seems too elaborate for Facebook privacy settings or even groups but was just wondering if it's possible?

Or if even if I hid it from my timeline, Nancy would see my like if she went to Joe'a page and his page settings weren't so private so that people can see his pictures.